# How to display data after update without refreshing the page using Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

I'm displaying data from a table on my Index.vue. When a user clicks the edit button a modal comes down and he can Update his information.

The update is successful, the new data is being inserted into the database. The problem is after he clicks the "Update" button, the data on the current page isn't refreshing. It only refreshes if I actually manually refresh the page. I'm new to Vue, maybe someone can help.

Here is my code:

```
mounted() {
            this.loadGroupedData();
        },

methods: {
            loadGroupedData: async function() {
                try {
                    const response = await groupedService.loadGroupedData();
                    this.resumes = response.data.resumes;
                    this.video_one = response.data.video_one;
                    this.video_two = response.data.video_two;
                    this.video_three = response.data.video_three;
                    this.photos = response.data.photos;
                    this.profiles = response.data.profiles;
                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
                }
            },

updateProfile: async function() {
                try {
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('photo_id', this.editProfileData.photo_id);
                    formData.append('employment_type', this.editProfileData.employment_type);
                    formData.append('date_of_birth', this.editProfileData.date_of_birth);
                    formData.append('experience', this.editProfileData.experience);
                    formData.append('skills', this.editProfileData.skills);
                    formData.append('resume_id', this.editProfileData.resume_id);
                    formData.append('video_one_id', this.editProfileData.video_one_id);
                    formData.append('video_two_id', this.editProfileData.video_two_id);
                    formData.append('video_three_id', this.editProfileData.video_three_id);

                    const response = await profileService.updateProfile(this.editProfileData.id, formData);

                    this.profiles.map(profile => {
                        if (profile.id == response.data.id) {
                            for (let key in response.data) {
                                profile[key] = response.data[key];
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    this.hideEditProfileModal();
                    this.$toast.success("Profile Updated Successfully!");
                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                }

            },
```

Basically, the first method is just returning a Json response. I am then displaying it on the page using v-for.

And the second is my Update function.

Here is my data. Everything is being inserted into 'profiles: []'. I'm storing ids in the profiles table instead of the file paths of the videos, photo and resume. So in my backend I'm fetching the data from those tables so I can get the file paths and display the output on the page.

```
data() {
            return {
                profiles: [],
                profile: [],
                video_one: [],
                video_two: [],
                video_three: [],
                resumes: [],
                photos: [],

                options: [
                    { text: "Full Time", value: "Full Time" },
                    { text: "Part Time", value: "Part Time" },
                ],

                profileData: {
                    photo_id: '',
                    employment_type: "Full Time",
                    date_of_birth: "",
                    experience: "",
                    skills: "",
                    resume_id: '',
                    video_one_id: '',
                    video_two_id: '',
                    video_three_id: ''
                },

                editProfileData: {
                    photo_id: '',
                    resume_id: '',
                    video_one_id: '',
                    video_two_id: '',
                    video_three_id: ''
                },

                errors: {}
            };
        },
```

Comment: 'loadGroupedData' is calling itself 'loadGroupedData'? Should it be calling another method? Like 'UpdateProfile'?

Comment: 'loadGroupedData' is the function that is displaying the data on the page initially when you go to that page. It's fetching Json data from my backend.

Comment: Hey @RyanSacks Did you resolve this issue? if yes can you please share the solution?